# Fitting a Bayesian Hierarchical Poisson Regression in R

Tags: r, generalized-linear-model, markov-chain-montecarlo, hierarchical-bayesian, poisson-regression

I'm trying to fit a Bayesian hierarchical poisson regression. To do so, I'm using MCMChpoisson function from MCMCpack in R. Based on this package, the model is:

$$Y_i \sim Poisson(\lambda_i)$$
$$\phi(\lambda_i) = X_i\beta + W_i \beta_i + \epsilon_i$$
$$\epsilon_i \sim N(0, \sigma^2 I_{k_i})$$
$$ \dots $$

In the model above, $\phi$ is the link function.

I skipped the rest of the model as only the parts of above are related to my question. My question is why they consider an measurement error ($\epsilon_i$) in the systematic component whereas in GLM we have a function of the mean; in other words, sampling from poisson will itself generate a measurement error.

Also, I think the extra $\epsilon_i$ term above causes me to get strange results. Does anyone know any other function/package in R to fit a model very similar to the model above with no measurement error in the systematic component.

Comment: FWIW, $\lambda$ for Poisson distribution is the mean.

Comment: $\varepsilon$ is an "overdispersion term". Described at the top of page 6 in [this writeup](http://www.samsi.info/sites/default/files/IMSM13_final_report.pdf). It doesn't seem like you can "turn it off" in `MCMChpoisson`.

Comment: If $\sigma=0$, the random effect gets away.

Comment: Thanks everyone. I understand that $\lambda$ is mean of the Poisson and that $\epsilon$ is an overdispersion term. THe point is my model does not need it.

Comment: @Xi'an, what do you mean that if $\sigma = 0$, then the random effect gets away? Random effect has it's own prior with mean and sigma. Could you elaborate more? Are you saying that in order to have random effect, I have to have the model this way? the model I'm fitting has only random intercept. Is there any reference that I can read more to see why $\epsilon$ is necessary? Also, if  it's necessary, why all my simulations with this model breaks?

Comment: @ssdecontrol, one way to "turn it off" might be putting an informative prior on $\sigma^2_{\epsilon}$ so that it always remains very close to zero.

Comment: @Xi'an, I decided to write my own hierarchical Bayesian code for longitudinal data with random intercept and with no $\epsilon$ in the model. It's working perfectly fine and I can retain the covariates with which I simulated my data. I wonder why you would think $\epsilon$ is required? Thanks for your feedback.

Comment: As @Xi'an pointed out, if $\sigma=0$, then $e_i=0$ for all $i$, i.e. it goes away. Real data is often overdispersed and thus typically including $\epsilon_i$ provides for a better model.